# Should a WiX setup for a Solution be created as an additional project in the Solution or as a separate Solution?

Tags: azure-devops, wix

I have a solution that consists of 5 projects (ASP.net Core Webservice and dlls). For this solution I want to create a setup using WiX. I'm working with Visual Studio 2019.

The solution is located in a Git repository in Azure DevOps.
There is already an automated build process that is executed after each pull request.
I want to extend this process (or create an additional one) so that the setup is also created automatically after the build.

Should I add the setup as another project to the existing solution or should I create a separate solution?
I don't have any experience with creating build pipelines in AzureDevOps yet, so I'm afraid that I might run into problems there later if I choose the "wrong" variant now.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the two variants?
Are there best practices for when to use which?

Comment: i would add the setup as another project to the existing solution. in my experience having your setup in an extra solution causes other devs to not check if the setups needs adjustment or if the setup builds at all.

Comment: Have you checked the following replies? Are they helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of personal choice but after 20+ years of installation development I prefer two solutions. The reasons are:

Pros:

1. It helps organize the repos to have Application code and Installer code.
2. Application developers don't have to have WiX installed. Projects won't fail to load in the application solution.
3. The application sln can be updated to a newer version of Visual Studio without waiting for the installation toolset to support the new version. This has historically been an issue.
4. Project dependency / project build order issues are moot because all application projects will build before any installer projects will.
5. Application developers don't have to worry about installer developers messing up their projects.
6. Because the projects are in different solutions you can't use project references which can be tricky and brittle.
7. Building application first and using postbuild file copy commands to create a model helps define what the installer should look like.
8. Installation projects frequently have to consume files from projects that may not even use visual studio at all or a combination of both.

Cons:

1. Separating the code can lead to an "us vs them" situation between application developers and installation developers.  However this can be mitigated by creating a clear understanding of roles and responsibilities.  Nothing stops developers from being aware of and contributing to either solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is a container that's used to organize one or more related code projects, for example a class library project and a corresponding test project. We'll look at the properties of a project and some of the files it can contain. We'll also create a reference from one project to another.

So if the WIX project relates to other projects in this solution, then add this setup as another project to the your existing solution.

Comment: How's your issue going?